# Does scikit-cuda support the newest version of pycuda (9.1) or do I have to revert to 7.5?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gpu, pycuda

I have installed pycuda and scikit cuda via pip install on python 3.6 and have been trying to run the following example from scikit cuda:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import numpy as np

import skcuda.linalg as culinalg
import skcuda.misc as cumisc
culinalg.init()

# Double precision is only supported by devices with compute
# capability >= 1.3:
import string
import scikits.cuda.cula as cula
demo_types = [np.float32, np.complex64]
if cula._libcula_toolkit == 'premium' and \
        cumisc.get_compute_capability(pycuda.autoinit.device) >= 1.3:
    demo_types.extend([np.float64, np.complex128])

for t in demo_types:
    print('Testing svd for type ' + str(np.dtype(t)))
    a = np.asarray((np.random.rand(50, 50) - 0.5) / 10, t)
    a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)
    u_gpu, s_gpu, vh_gpu = culinalg.svd(a_gpu)
    a_rec = np.dot(u_gpu.get(), np.dot(np.diag(s_gpu.get()), vh_gpu.get()))

    print('Success status: ', np.allclose(a, a_rec, atol=1e-3))
    print('Maximum error: ', np.max(np.abs(a - a_rec)))
    print('')
```

which then prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-a4adfb24f4ca>", line 8, in <module>
    import skcuda.linalg as culinalg

  File "C:\Users\moore\downloadsl\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skcuda\linalg.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import cublas

  File "C:\Users\moore\downloadsl\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skcuda\cublas.py", line 55, in <module>
    raise OSError('cublas library not found')

OSError: cublas library not found
```

I looked into the cublas.py and there is a list of versions and it only goes upto 7.5, so my question is threefold. Are the newest versions of pycuda and scikit-cuda compatible and if not, are there any analogous libraries for nvidia gpu acceleration of gpu code that is as easy as scikit-cuda, and if not what versions will I have to download in order to make this all work?

Comment: Are you sure your system has all the dependencies as mentioned here:- https://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installation-dependencies

Comment: I don't have CULA and all of the download links are broken on the CULA website. I also would prefer to use open source packages. I'm not sure why scikit opted to use CULA

Comment: The more I look at the various GPU libraries, the more I get discouraged. Either I don't know enough to even begin to touch these libraries or they are so depreciated that they don't work. I'm ideally looking for a python library that can parallelize linear algebra algorithms, but I can't find anything. Maybe with modern cpus linear algebra is best left to blas and laPACK and gpus are best left to machine learning tasks?

Comment: You can just use TensorFlow for linear algebra and it will nicely run on CPUs and GPUs.

Comment: Historical note: the initial motivation for scikit-cuda was to facilitate the use of certain GPU-based functions provided by CULA that were not available in other libraries at the time (e.g., svd) but were in the academic edition of CULA. Although CULA is still commercially available, EM Photonics no longer distributes an academic edition.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same issue. Tested with many python versions, many cuda versions and many scikit-cuda versions :(